# Running node.js express app worldwide on Debian VM on ipv4 address

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, debian

Hi i have a problem and i stuck on it since few days. I try tu run my express app on my own computer on debian vm. I think i tried every possible way to run it. I use Ipv4 addres. My last attempt is this:
`app.listen(3000, '0.00.000.000');` (there are other numbers in place of the zeros). I already tried using nodemon and forever

Comment: is the port open to your server?

Comment: Yeah i open porst's on my router, on the firewall and on VM

Comment: When you make a request to your server on port 3000, what is returned?

Comment: You can be behind a larger 'lan' hence your 'public' IP is only local to that LAN (Carrier grade NAT). Also, how did you find out what your public IP is? just to be sure you're not using the LAN ip.